Is there any solution to remove default style from wordpress for the backend
.editor-styles-wrapper h1,
.editor-styles-wrapper h2,
.editor-styles-wrapper h3,
.editor-styles-wrapper h4,
.editor-styles-wrapper h5,
.editor-styles-wrapper h6,
.editor-styles-wrapper p,
.wp-block-cover-image .block-editor-block-list__block,
.wp-block-cover .block-editor-block-list__block {
    color: inherit !important;
}

This css overrides with my color selection and do not show the correct color for text in the backend.
I have tried many functions to dequeue this style but it is still showing.

You need a more accurate CSS selector so that you can override !important.
